# Getting insufficient memory exception in a exe started with Cruisecontrol.Net

Tags: memory, cruisecontrol.net

As part of deployment process, I am starting an .net remoting windows forms application through the Cruisecontrol.Net (version 1.4.4) and getting insufficient memory exception while calling a document generation process.  However, I am not getting the error if I run the windows forms application directly after logging into the server.

Has anyone faced this peculiar problem with cruise control / does cruise contol enforce any particular memory constraint on the executable launched from within its process space.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you still get the exception when you run CruiseControl.Net from the command line (i.e. as the current user, not LocalService)?

The OutOfMemoryException may be a red herring, maybe the application is missing write access to a location it needs?

Answer (score 2):

Are you using the service? Because the service should not be trying to bring up any GUIs (you mentioned winforms) If you try to bring one up, it will not work, maybe that is the true reason for the exception?

Comment: I am trying to bring up a winform, but it launches correctly and I am able to perform all the normal operations with the application.  Only the correspondence generation is having issue, so I am not sure whether launching the windows form from cruise control is an issue by itself.